# Referencing a template in Twig / Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

A Twig template in one bundle calls another Twig template in another bundle, but I can't reference it.

The file is in this folder:

```
src/Company/Bundle/ActivityBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig
```

And I am trying to reference it from a Twig file in another bundle like this:

```
{% extends "Company/Bundle/ActivityBundle/index.html.twig" %}
```

I've tried every possible combination, but it just doesn't pick it up and I get a "Twig_Error_Loader: Unable to find template" error

Comment: Have you tried `@CompanyActivityBundle:Default:index.html.twig`?

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it didn't work, but later I tried it without the @ part and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've missed `Default` part of template path:

```
{% extends "Company/Bundle/ActivityBundle/Default/index.html.twig" %}
```

or as I prefer much more:

```
{% extends "CompanyBundleActivityBundle:Default:index.html.twig" %}
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: CompanyActivityBundle:Default:index.html.twig did it but your answer was very close and allowed me to get there. Thanks