# Sylius: How to reference your own twig template in a grid?

Tags: symfony, templates, grid, symfony4, sylius

This is not a duplicate of e.g. [Referencing a template in Twig / Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528270/referencing-a-template-in-twig-symfony2) because creating bundles as applications is deprecated/not recommended anymore and therefore the answer is not applicable anymore. How do I reference my own template in a Sylius grid?

What I tried:

1.

```
                options:
                    template: "@App/Order/Grid/Field/channel.html.twig"
```

2.

```
                options:
                    template: ":Order/Grid/Field:channel.html.twig"
```

3.

```
                options:
                    template: "templates/Order/Grid/Field/channel.html.twig"
```

4.

```
                options:
                    template: "Order/Grid/Field/channel.html.twig"
```

(I tried some of these on the basis of the documentation: https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.6/components_and_bundles/bundles/SyliusGridBundle/field_types.html#twig-twig , https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.6/components_and_bundles/bundles/SyliusGridBundle/your_first_grid.html)

In all cases it says the template was not found. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you create grid or customize them? For example, I am trying to customize Admin > Catalog > Options grid, so by [this tutorial](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.6/customization/grid.html#how-to-customize-fields-of-a-grid) put these lines at the end of `config/packages/_sylius.yaml` file:

```
sylius_grid:
    grids:
        sylius_admin_product_option:
            fields:
                name:
                    type: twig
                    options:
                        template: "Grid/mytemplate.html.twig"
```

Secondly, I create folder "Order" in /templates, then "Grid" folder in "Order" dir, and then folder "Field" in "Grid" directory. There I create file "mytemplate.html.twig" with any content. Did you tried similar steps?

Comment: Yes, thank you! It's very strange, I have it exactly like you now: 

sylius_grid:
    grids:
        sylius_admin_order:
            fields:
                channel:
                    path: .
                    options:
                        template: "Order/Grid/Field/channel.html.twig"

I have it in templates/Order/Grid/Field/channel.html.twig. He can't find it.

Comment: And that definition is indeed in _sylius.yaml and templates/ folder is located in project root. Cache is cleaned and it says it even looks there at that exact location but still cannot find the template although it is undoubtedly there.

"Unable to find template "Order/Grid/Field/channel.html.twig" (looked into: <project_root>\vendor\knplabs\knp-menu\src\Knp\Menu/Resources/views, <project_root>/templates, <project_root>/templates, <project_root>\vendor\symfony\twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form)."

Comment: This is very weird, indeed. I just got it to work: I put the channel.html.twig directly under templates/ and changed the template path in the grid definition accordingly. And it worked! Then I put the template under templates/Order/ and it again worked. Then I put it under templates/Order/Grid/ - including changing the path definition and it's not working again, putting it under templates/Order/ again makes it work. Why is that? Any ideas? Is there a specification I missed?

Comment: when you put it under templates/Order/Grid/ , how was your path looked like?

Comment: template: "Order/Grid/channel.html.twig"

I have it under templates/Order for now and it's working, although I would rather have it under Order/Grid which is for some reason reproducibly not working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Omg. Found it. There was a space in the beginning of the Grid folder name -.- Solved.

Comment: Oh its was so painful issue, in programming there is one great suggestion when completely out of ideas - delete all your changes and try again from the beginning. Fortunately git can easily help with it